# Remix (or any other tool): Solidity program to EVM opcode

Tags: solidity, remix, opcode

I am interested in obtaining sequence of opcodes for a Solidity program:

One example is given in the following program obtained from
[Link of paper](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/97207/hildenbrandt-saxena-zhu-rodrigues-guth-daian-rosu-2017-tr.pdf)

I have attached the image [image: Image of Solidity Opcodes]also
I need a link to a tool which can perform this task. How can we do it on Remix?

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: You can use remix. After compiling a contract in the compiler section click on "Compilation Details". In the popup look at the "Assembly" section.

Comment: Download solc, and run `solc --asm YourContractFileName ` from a command-line terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling on remix IDE got to compilation Details. look at the assembly section. You'll get a similar view to the link

[image: remix ide assembly code]